# how to change L5 jwt-auth Storage - providers.storage to redis

Tags: laravel-5, jwt, predis

Some one can me help me how to change provider to predis

```
'storage' => function ($app) { 
    return new Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\IlluminateCacheAdapter($app['cache']);
}
```

Comment: BTW, you need it only for blacklisting. In general tokens are not stored.

Comment: @mina Youssef that true. In my case i wanted to blacklist the current token after it has been refreshed. other wise it is accepting the previous tokens

Comment: What about the expiry? Do you refresh tokens that did not expire?

Comment: exactly. i'm implementing the single window method

Comment: But why are you blacklisting the token, it will expire sooner or later.